# RShiny branched successive inputs

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity, shinyjs

***EDIT: Updated with a slightly better code.***

I'm working on a very clunky UI that has branches of inputs....but I'm wondering if I should be doing it a different way, possibly on the server side? I want to progress down through the inputs as each one is selected, and **to not show** the next input until the previous is set.  Ultimately each decision tree leads to a data table being displayed from a server side SQL function. (I created two similar functions, one which renders a table with a single select, and one that renders with multi select.  Then the selected rows from the table will be sent back to the server along with the inputs via a submit button.

Ultimately I am trying to augment this app: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/phylo-tree-view-subset.html
to have a branch that lets a user manipulate custom data, and then feed it back to the tree plotting function.

Should I be trying to do this sort of input structure on the server instead of UI?  If so, is there a decent example somewhere? I'm struggling trying to see how the various demos would work with this.

I have a tree of inputs like so:

```
1) Do you have a file to upload? (yes/no)
    a)Yes
        1)File type (list)
        2)Choose file (file explorer)
    b)No
        1)Choose single sample or multiple sample: (single/multiple)
             a)Single
                 1)choose type: (otu/sequence)
                      a)anychoice 
                          1)Abundance or Incidence? (abundance/incidence)
                               a)abundance
                                    1)Slider for value between 0-10,000
                          2)Distance method (list of options)
                          3) Display datatable (select single row)
                          4) Submit button
              a)Multiple
                 1)choose type: (otu/sequence)
                      a)anychoice 
                          1)Abundance or Incidence? (abundance/incidence)
                               a)abundance
                                    1)Slider for value between 0-10,000
                          2)Cluster method (list of options)
                          3)Distance method (list of options)
                          4) Display datatable (select multiple rows)
                          5) Submit button
```

Current code, its not giving all the functionality I want, but I'm still chipping away at it.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- shinyUI(tagList(
useShinyalert(),
useShinyjs(),
navbarPage(
title = "Phylogenetic Tree Subsetting",
tabPanel(
  title = "Explore Tree",

  fluidRow(
    class = "inputs",


    column(
      4,
      selectInput(
        inputId = "own_file",
        label = "Do you already have a tree file to upload?",
        choices = c("No" = "no",
                    "Yes" = "yes",
                    " " = " "),
        selected = " "
      )
    ),

    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.own_file == 'yes'",

                     column(
                       4,
                       selectInput(
                         inputId = "file_type",
                         label = "Select Tree File Type:",
                         choices = c(
                           "Tree" = "tree",
                           "Beast" = "beast",
                           # "CodeML" = "codeml",
                           "CodeML mlc" = "mlc",
                           # "HYPHY" = "hyphy",
                           "jplace" = "jplace",
                           "MrBayes" = "mrbayes",
                           "NHX" = "nhx",
                           "rst (CODEML/BASEML)" = "rst",
                           "phylip" = "phylip",
                           # "r8s" = "r8s",
                           "RAxML" = "raxml"
                         ),
                         selected = "tree"
                       )
                     ),
                     column(
                       4,
                       fileInput(inputId = "upload_tree",
                                 label = "Select Tree File:")
                     )),


    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.own_file == 'no'",

      column(
        4,
        selectInput(
          inputId = "tree_type",
          label = "Would you like to view a single sample, or cluster multiple samples?",
          choices = c(
            "Single" = "single",
            "Multiple" = "multiple",
            " " = " "
          ),
          selected = " "
        )
      ),


      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.tree_type == 'single'",

        column(
          4,
          selectInput(
            inputId = "cluster_type1",
            label = "View by Organism, or by Sequence?",
            choices = c(
              Choose = '',
              OTU = 'otu',
              Sequence = 'sequence'
            ),
            selectize = FALSE
          )
        ),

        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.cluster_type1 == 'sequence'|input.cluster_type1 == 'otu'",
          column(
            4,
            selectInput(
              inputId = "presence_type1",
              label = "Generate tree from Presence/Absence, or Relative Abundance?",
              choices = c(
                Choose = '',
                Incidence = 'incidence',
                Abundance = 'abundance'
              ),
              selectize = FALSE

            )

          ),

          conditionalPanel(condition = "input.presence_type1 == 'abundance'",

                           column(
                             4,
                             sliderInput(
                               "norm_value1",
                               "Choose normalization value: (Use keyboard arrows to fine tune value.)",
                               min = 0,
                               max = 10000,
                               value = 3999
                             )

                           )),

          conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.presence_type1 == 'incidence'|input.presence_type1 == 'abundance'",
            column(
              4,
              selectInput(
                inputId = "distance_method1",
                label = "Which distance method would you like to use for the distance matrix?",
                choices = c(
                  "Manhattan" = "manhattan",
                  "Canberra" = "canberra",
                  "Bray" = "bray",
                  "Kulczynski" = "kulczynski",
                  "Jaccard" = "jaccard",
                  "Gower" = "gower",
                  "AltGower" = "altGower",
                  "Morisita" = "morisita",
                  "Horn" = "horn",
                  "Mountford" = "mountford",
                  "Raup" = "raup",
                  "Binomial" = "binomial",
                  "Chao" = "chao",
                  "Cao" = "cao",
                  "Mahalanobis" = "mahalanobis"
                ),
                selected = "gower"
              )
            ),

            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.distance_method1 == 'bray'|input.norm_value1 == '4000'",
                             column(
                               4,
                               DT::dataTableOutput("tbl1"),
                               actionButton(
                                 "button",
                                 "SUBMIT",
                                 style = "background-color:#221B70;
                                 color:#E0EB15;
                                 border-color:#E61029;
                                 border-style:double;
                                 border-width:4px;
                                 border-radius:50%;
                                 font-size:19px;"
                               )
                               ))
                               )
                               )
                               )
                               ),


    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.tree_type == 'multiple'",

      column(
        4,
        selectInput(
          inputId = "cluster_type2",
          label = "View by Organism, or by Sequence?",
          choices = c(
            Choose = '',
            OTU = 'otu',
            Sequence = 'sequence'
          ),
          selectize = FALSE
        )
      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.cluster_type2 == 'sequence'|input.cluster_type2 == 'otu'",
        column(
          4,
          selectInput(
            inputId = "presence_type2",
            label = "Generate tree from Presence/Absence, or Relative Abundance?",
            c(
            Choose = '',
            Incidence = 'incidence',
            Abundance = 'abundance'
          ),
          selectize = FALSE
        )
        ),


        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.presence_type2 == 'abundance'",

                         column(
                           4,
                           sliderInput(
                             "norm_value2",
                             "Choose normalization value: (Use keyboard arrows to fine tune value.)",
                             min = 0,
                             max = 10000,
                             value = 3999
                           )

                         )),


        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.presence_type2 == 'incidence'|input.presence_type2 == 'abundance'",
          column(
            4,
            selectInput(
              inputId = "cluster_method",
              label = "Which clustering method would you like to use?",
              choices = c(
                "Ward.D" = "ward.D",
                "Ward.D2" = "ward.D2",
                "Single" = "single",
                "Complete" = "complete",
                "Average (= UPGMA)" = "average",
                "Mcquitty (= WPGMA)" = "mcquitty",
                "Median (= WPGMC)" = "median",
                "Centroid (= UPGMC)" = "centroid"
              ),
              selected = "single"
            )
          ),


          conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.cluster_method == 'ward.D2'",
            column(
              4,
              selectInput(
                inputId = "distance_method2",
                label = "Which distance method would you like to use for the distance matrix?",
                choices = c(
                  "Manhattan" = "manhattan",
                  "Canberra" = "canberra",
                  "Bray" = "bray",
                  "Kulczynski" = "kulczynski",
                  "Jaccard" = "jaccard",
                  "Gower" = "gower",
                  "AltGower" = "altGower",
                  "Morisita" = "morisita",
                  "Horn" = "horn",
                  "Mountford" = "mountford",
                  "Raup" = "raup",
                  "Binomial" = "binomial",
                  "Chao" = "chao",
                  "Cao" = "cao",
                  "Mahalanobis" = "mahalanobis"
                ),
                selected = "gower"
              )
            ),

            conditionalPanel(
              condition = "input.distance_method2 == 'bray'|input.norm_value2 == '4000'",
              DT::dataTableOutput("tbl2"),
              actionButton(
                "button",
                "SUBMIT",
                style = "background-color:#221B70;
                color:#E0EB15;
                border-color:#E61029;
                border-style:double;
                border-width:4px;
                border-radius:50%;
                font-size:19px;"
              )
              )
              )
              )
              )
              )

              ),
  uiOutput("select_node_render"),
  fluidRow(uiOutput("subtree_render"))
          )
        )
    ))

server <- function(input, output){

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```